# Error:Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, multithreading

This following code gives me an error that "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox30' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,S ystem.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[bytes];
    byte[] ar = new byte[20];
    byte[] ssd = new byte[4];
    byte[] ctrl = new byte[20];
    string pp = "";
    string ll = "";
    serialPort1.Read(byte_buffer, 0, bytes);
    int index = byte_buffer[0];

    array[index] = TestSerializer.MarshalToStructureArray(byte_buffer,bytes);
    textBox30.Text = index.ToString();
    serialPort1.Write("N");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Can any one Suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the InvokeRequired issue.

Instead of:

```
textBox30.Text = index.ToString();
```

Try:

```
textBox30.Invoke(s => textBox30.Text = s, index.ToString())
```

More Info: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/invokerequired/info)

Comment: I write like this   if (textBox30.InvokeRequired)
            {
                
               this.Invoke(((MethodInvoker)delegate
               {
                   textBox30.Text=index.ToString();
               }));
              //  return;
            }